# Find the holomorphic function knowing the imaginary part and $f(0)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$

$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

imaginary part : $v(x,y)=y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$

and $f(0)=0$

Comment: Hint: What do the Cauchy-Riemann equations tell you?

Comment: Did you make a transcription error? $v$ is singular at $z=0$, how can it have a finite value there?

Comment: no i didn't . i just copied the exercise as it is .

Comment: i know that the cauchy riemann eqts tell me that if du/dx=dv/dy then the fct is holomorphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically solve this by inspection (looking at it).

Consider $f(z) = z + 1/z$ with $z=x+iy$.

$$f(x+iy) = x+iy + \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2} = x+ \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+ i \left(y - \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right) = u(x,y)+ i v(x,y)$$

Thus $u(x,y) = x+ \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} + \textrm{const.}$ and $f(z) = z+1/z+\textrm{real const.}$

Since the $f(z)$ we found is unique, up to a constant, we cannot find a holomorphic function  with this imaginary part in a domain that contains the origin!  Also, forget about satisfying the condition $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

We have $v(x,y)=y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$

$v_x=\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2},\qquad v_y=1-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=1+\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

$v_{xx}=\frac{2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\frac{8x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^3}=\frac{2y(y^2-3x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3},\qquad v_{yy}=\frac{2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\frac{4y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}=\frac{2y(3x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$

Clearly, $v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$ and hence $v(x,y)$ satisfies Laplace equation.

Now since $f(z)$ is holomorphic, so $u_x=v_y \qquad \text{and} \qquad u_y=-v_x$.

$u_y=-v_x=-\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\implies u(x,y)=-\int \frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dy \qquad $(taking $x$ as constant)

$\implies u(x,y)=x\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}+g(x)\qquad$where $g(x)$ is a function of $x$.

$\implies u_x=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}+g'(x)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}+g'(x)=1+\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\qquad$ as  $u_x=v_y$

$\implies g'(x)=1\implies g(x)=x+c \qquad$ where $c$ is integrating  constant.

So $u(x,y)= \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+x+c$

Therefore $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+x+c)+i(y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$

Comment: You meant to say $g$ is a real differentiable function of $x$? And $c$ is a real constant.

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Comment: You are welcome.